# Why is the value of variable different when using CCLog and using print in debug mode?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

The strengthbar in my game doesn't work well after playing at least once of the level. So I wrote a method using CCLog to log out some variables and call this method in update: method. And I also set a breakpoint, when this problem appears it gets into debug mode of Xcode, then I use print to check the variables. However it appears that the values are different between using CCLog and using print command. Here's a screenshot that explains everything.

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

Does it have something to do with Multithreads(which I know nothing about)? I've checked the declaration of each logged variables, to make sure they're not declared several times using the same name.

Comment: Try call `[self cclogStrength]` inside `consumeStrength`. I am pretty sure that values will be the same.

Comment: I tried [self cclogStrength] and you were right. The values are the same. Does this have something to do with releasing the level scene that was played last time? The testing flow is: 1 Run game 2 Choosing level scene 3 play level one 4 win, back to level scene 5 play Level one again. It only appears sometimes at step 5.

Comment: I tested again and find out that the memory addresses of Gamelayer scene's _strengthbar and the strengthbar which contains the error is different. But when it is right(playing the first time), the two addresses are the same.

Comment: I'm sure now that the old level scene is not released properly. So every touch is received by two scenes. This problems seems has something to do with CCBReader. I don't know what I can do about it because I'm using ARC.

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem is solved.

When I wrote some delegate I used "Strong" which causes some retain cycles. Now I changed them all to Weak, and also changed the deployment settings to iOS 5 (or above).

The reason that the values of the variable are different is because in CCLog, the value belongs to the new scene, however there're more than one scene at the same time receiving my touches because of the retain cycles. Nothing wrong about XCode or Cocos2d, or CCBReader :-p

Hope this answer would help others. And many thanks to @Cy-4AH.

Answer (score 0):

Because it was changed after it was printed. In the breakpoint you are lookng at new value.

Comment: It's only maybe 1/60 time between printing and breaking. I guess there must be something wrong. It's very weird that this error doesn't occur if you play this level once, even if you play this level many times, it does not always appear. It really drives me crazy.